# Matlab remove last null value of a vector

Tags: matlab

I have a vector

```
X = [1 2 3 0 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0]
```

and I want to remove all last values if there are null.

```
Result = [1 2 3 0 5 6 7 8 9]
```

But as you can see, the fourth value stays present in the result even if it is a null value.

I try to do it without loop to use lesser as possible time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
index = find(X>0,1,'last');
X=X(1:index);
```

Comment: It's actually a bit easier than that. You don't need the `>0`. The following works: `X = X(1:find(X, 1, 'last'));`